# Fiscal month from date in OBIEE

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

How do I get the fiscal month in order (like Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug.....Feb,Mar) from date in OBIEE?

Comment: I am able to get the month but it is coming in alphabetical order like Apr,Aug,Dec,Feb,Jan,Jul,Jun,Mar,May,Nov,Oct,Sep. but I want it in order like Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug........Feb,Mar. Please help

Comment: Please show some code or table structure here.

Comment: CASE MONTHNAME(CAST("Reservation_c"."ABREISE_CHECKOUTDATE_c" AS DATE)) WHEN '01' THEN 'Jan' WHEN '02' THEN 'Feb' WHEN '03' THEN 'Mar' WHEN '04' THEN 'Apr' WHEN '05' THEN 'May' WHEN '06' THEN 'Jun' WHEN '07' THEN 'Jul' WHEN '08' THEN 'Aug' WHEN '09' THEN 'Sep' WHEN '10' THEN 'Oct' WHEN '11' THEN 'Nov' ELSE 'Dec' END

Comment: The easy way is to maintain a calendar table that includes various fiscal columns.  Where I work, the field is called fiscal_period.

Comment: In My case I have only one date field i.e "Reservation_c"."ABREISE_CHECKOUTDATE_c" and I am using it to get month by using MONTH() function.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation contains all you need:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e10540/sqlref.htm#BIEMG546

MONTHNAME(<>) gives you the name. MONTH(<>) gives you its number. And that number you can then use to sort the name.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help. I already did the same and getting the result.